# Transparent/white goo on the back of lemon tree leafs

Tags: trees, diseases, lemons

The tree has been outside during the summer, since a few weeks back I took it in. A few days back I noticed these strange things attached on the back of 20% of the leafs. What is it?

[image: sad lemon tree leaf]

[image: sad lemon tree leaf]
[image: sad lemon tree leaf]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While manually removing the white goo (whatever it was) with a few cotton pads, I noticed a few white flies. After some googling, I found a matching picture of a whitefly. The liquid drops seems to be Honeydew, which is "a sticky byproduct of their feeding, may coat leaves and anything under the tree, such as benches or vehicles." ([see this article](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/whiteflies-lemon-trees-53937.html) for more info)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be mealybugs on your lemon tree. If you can isolate a few and examine under magnification compare to the [images here](https://uscitrus.com/blogs/citrus-simplified/mealy-bugs-are-destroying-my-citrus-plant-what-do-i-do) and see if they match up. If the plant is reasonably small one simple treatment is to use a Qtip and rubbing alcohol to wipe off the patches you see. Keep a watchful eye for new patches, and repeat until they are all gone.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can find a magnification glass. Do you know what the drops can be? looks like tiny tiny rain drops.

Comment: Colin, I found it was whiteflies!